# EF Database First Scaffolding DateTime Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, scaffolding, ef-database-first

I have created a database table with a DateTime column.

Datetime stored in db as `2013/06/21 00:00`

Upon scaffolding, the datetime column auto displays to user in local format `21/06/2013 00:00` which is not what was specifically specified, but no real complaints.

Problem comes when editing the scaffolded column, it also displays to user in textbox in `21/06/2013 00:00` and not in format `2013/06/21 00:00`

As such, datetime will always fail validation unless user manually converts to `2013/06/21 00:00`

Have i done something wrong?

When scaffolding, I never asked it to display date in Local format. And if it is automatically going to display the date to local format, then surely it should automatically convert the date to international format???

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Write this before the DateTime property of your class:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

for example:

```
public partial class MyModel
{
    // something ...

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }

    // something other ...
}
```